# Languages switcher. HTML, CSS, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two long lists. These lists include different jobs. One list written in English. Another one - in Dutch. I have two buttons. When I click the "English" button, it switches everything into English, and the "Dutch" button turns on the Dutch list. What is the best way to write the html code. I mean should I do as it is below? Or maybe put languages interchangeably line after line. And by the way, there gonna be around 6 different languages.

```html
<ul class="eng-list">
  <li>
    <h2>Gardener</h2>
    <p>Description of what the gardener does.
      <img src="url-some-pic-of-a-gardener">
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Farmer</h2>
    <p>Description of what the farmer does.
      <img src="url-some-pic-of-a-farmer">
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
<ul class="dutch-list">
  <li>
    <h2>Gardener</h2>
    <p>Description of what the gardener does in Dutch.
      <img src="url-some-pic-of-a-gardener">
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Farmer</h2>
    <p>Description of what the farmer does in Dutch.
      <img src="url-some-pic-of-a-farmer">
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: There's necessarily no "right" way to do this, so the answers you get will be opinion-based. Consider edit your question or it might be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather use a JSON structure (just a sample):

```js
list = { element: 
          { 
            "job": { 
                "en": "Gardener",
                "nl": "Gardener in Dutch",
                "es": "Jardinero",
                ...
              },
            "description": { "en": "What a gardener does...",
                             "nl": "What a gardener does in Dutch...",
                             "es": "Lo que hace un jardinero...",
                             ...
                            },
            "picture": "IMG_gardener.jpg"
          },
         element: 
           {
            "job": {
                "en": "Farmer",
                "nl": "Farmer in Dutch",
                "es": "Granjero",
                ...
            },
            "description": { "en": "What a farmer does...",
                             "nl": "What a farmer does in Dutch...",
                             "es": "Lo que hace un granjero...",
                             ...
                           },
            "picture": "IMG_farmer.jpg"

          },
       };
```

It would be easy to display on screen as desired and extend to *n* languages with a little additional js.